# accessing second instance of element to invoke different data

Tags: javascript, dom, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to access the second instance of '`div.question.question-dropdown input`'. I have tried incorporating the typical `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()` type pseudo selectors but they are being ignored. Below is the JS code I'm trying to achieve; but adding the unique `Data` to the second instance (but can't find a way to unique select).

```
                .waitForElementVisible("div.question.question-dropdown input",400)
                .click('div.question.question-dropdown input')

                .setValue('div.question.question-dropdown input', Data.CreateOpp.motivation)

                .pause(500)

                .waitForElementVisible("div.question.question-dropdown input",400)

                .click('div.question.question-dropdown input')

                .setValue('div.question.question-dropdown input', Data.CreateOpp.motivation)

                .pause(500)

                .click('div.question-btn.question-btn-submit')
```

The mark-up is 2 different input form fields, within 2 `div.question.question-dropdown`.

```
<!-- first -->
<div class="question question-dropdown">
    <div class="smart-input">
       <label></label>
       <input>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- second -->
<div class="question question-dropdown">
    <div class="smart-input">
       <label></label>
       <input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the corresponding html too please

Comment: there is no second input in your HTML, so how could it find it?

Comment: and where did you use your `nth-child` then? `div.question.question-dropdown:nth-of-type(2) input` should work.

Comment: ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <div.question.question-dropdown:nth-of-type(2) input> to be present for 400 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion nth selector should work:

`"div.question.question-dropdown:nth-of-type(2) input"`

But if not, you can try XPath:

`"(//div[@class="question question-dropdown"])[1]//input"`

Comment: Error while running click command: Provided locating strategy is not supported: div.question.question-dropdown:nth-of-type(2) input. It must be one of the following:
class name, css selector, id, name, link text, partial link text, tag name, xpath

Comment: what browser if it's not supported? it's a valid CSS3 selector